# hooking up a battery tender to your car for the winter

Tags: battery

Do I need to disconnect my battery to use a battery tender for the winter? Is there the possibility of damaging the charging system if I leave the cables connected? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**No**, you do not need to disconnect the battery from the vehicle before applying a battery tender. Ensure, however, that you disconnect the battery tender from the vehicle before you go to start it. If you don't, some tenders will self destruct.